# SQL Query on Ranks

Tags: sql

Hi can any one help me out with this scenario.

```
studentname sub1 sub2 sub3
abc          10   20   30
def          20   50   70
fsa          20   10   80
```

The result must look like

```
StudentName     Rank
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: How do you calculate the rank? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to take their 3 subject total or the average among themselves or with your own static numbers to rank? E.g. total>75...

Comment: try my sample post, it will get the rank base on the average of your sub1,sub2,sub3

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
RANK ( ) OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

See it here:
[RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

Try this: if you are trying to get the ave of the three subjects((sub1+sub2+sub3)/3)

```
select StudentName, RANK() OVER  (order by (sub1+sub2+sub3)/3 asc) Rank
from TableName
```